# Mensaje Flash no se muestra en la vista

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

estoy tratando de mostrar un mensaje flash (un div alert-success) con un mensaje de confirmacion pero no se porque no se muestra en la vista.

El Insert lo hago desde un modal que se deberia cerrar al terminar de hacer la insercion y luego redireccionarme a la vista mostrandome el alert informativo, pero solamente se hace el insert y no se muestra el mensaje.

Codigo de la Vista:

```
 @if ($message = Session::get("success"))
<div class="alert alert-success alert-block ">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
</div>
@endif
```

Codigo del Controlador:

```
    public function store(Request $request){
            Servicio::updateOrCreate(['id' => $request->id],
            ['servicio' => $request->servicio, 'observaciones' => 
$request->observaciones, 'status' => $request->status]);
session()->flash('success','Estariamos OK');
            return response(); 
         }
```

EDIT: Actualize los codigos pero solo me funciona el mensaje usando el return redirect() y actualizando la vista, no lo muestra automaticamente...
Me estare saltando algo?

Saludos a todos

Comment: Buen día, espero te sirva este comentario, el Flash embebido o adicionado como pluging en los exploradores, tengo entendido que ya no esta soportado desde el primero de enero del presente año.  En su lugar podrías utilizar swetalert que es un pluging js y permite mostrar alertas con diversos formatos, iconos tendrías que revisar su sitio web para que tengas una idea  https://sweetalert2.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

Los mensajes flash también puedes usarlos de la siguiente manera:

```
return back()->with('success', 'Estaríamos OK');
```

Estos se muestran cuando la página se recarga, porque Laravel es php y php se maneja así desde siempre. A no ser que uses Livewire o Inertiajs, lo cual tiene otras formas para hacerlo.

Ahora, si quieres obtener un mensaje de sesión y mostrarlo al momento de actualizar via ajax, debes enviar la respuesta de la siguiente manera:

```
return response(['success' => 'Estaríamos OK']);
```

Esto al recibirlo en tu método, mostrará en las herramientas de inspección, en la sección networking, la ruta al que enviaste la petición y esta, en su sección response, debe mostrarse un mensaje en formato json así

```
{'success': 'Estariamos OK'}
```

Con un status 200.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('search');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  fetch('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/1')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      $('#message').html(`<p style="color: green; font-size: 20px; font-weight: 700; margin: 2rem;">Estariamos OK</p>
      
      <img src=${res.image}>`);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div id="message">
  </div>
  <button id="search">Buscar</button>
</div>
```

Imagina que en el snippet lo que recibes, es decir, en este caso mi *res.image*, es tu response que envías y es lo que pintarías finalmente en tu div